# Count children of a div, perform calc and set css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to count the children of a div and then set the width of the parent. The issue I have is the data is dynamically loading so I never know how many children there will be. The parent is taking the total width of all the children and setting the incorrect width (too large).

For example, 4 children, it sets 4 x 750px. Making the parent div 3000px.

So I was thinking I could use jquery to count the divs, take the width of the parent and divide it by jquery count of the children.

```
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="box-slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="box-slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="box-slide">Slide 3</div>
<div class="box-slide">Slide 4</div>
</div>
```

The output is like this:

```
outer-container: width: 3000px
box-slider: width: 750px
```

I need the outer container to be 750px. Some will ask why don't I hard code the outer container. These div are responsive and should be 100% of the container they sit in.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume your box-slide class items (children) are of fixed width. In that case, you have to consider some things:

Since they are 750px, they may look good in a FHD, HD monitor, but in QHD not. Depends on how you are sorting items. If you don't know the width of the items and the parent should be this size, consider using display: table | table-row | table-cell to automatically generate fit sized items:

```
    <style>
        .DisplayTable{
            display: table;
        }.DisplayTableCell{
            display: table-cell;
        }.DisplayTableRow{
            display: table-row;
        }

        .LeftFloated{
            float: left;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="DisplayTable"></div>
        <div class="DisplayTableRow">
            <div class="DisplayTableCell LeftFloated">A</div>
            <div class="DisplayTableCell LeftFloated">A</div>
            <div class="DisplayTableCell LeftFloated">A</div>
            <div class="DisplayTableCell LeftFloated">A</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var children = document.getElementsByClassName("DisplayTableCell LeftFloated");
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            console.log( "Width: " + children[i].offsetWidth );

        console.log( children[0].parentElement.offsetWidth );
    </script>
```

The output in console is: width of each children in px, and the width of the parent fitting the most children possible in it. This doesn't takes in consideration overflows.

In my example and according to my browser font size, the output is:

```
12 -> Children[0]
12 -> Children[1]
12 -> Children[2]
12 -> Children[3]
48 -> Parent element
```

Comment: All that assuming gains you nothing by answering an off topic question (one that doesn't ask a question) and will be closed shortly. Don't waste your time answering off topic questions. "Not all questions can or should be answered here": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Well, I understood what he (or she?) meant. Easy dude, you gain nothing spreading your "I want his question closed" through the comments. If you didn't understand it and think this is offtopic, just flag it and stay out. In the end the yellow box with text will state the reason it was closed.

I understood what he tried to say (He's new). He couldn't explain very well his doubts but at least I could try help him( or her?)... That's what matters.

Comment: I see that all the time. "I knew what he meant" only to have the questioner come back later saying, "No, that's not what I meant".  Don't assume. It's a waste of time.

Comment: Don't worry, I have enough time :)

Comment: No, nothing is of static width. All of this sits in the bootstrap frame work. I stated 750px as an example. I would like pointing in the right direction of how i get jQuery to count children of a div, get the width of the parent and perform a calc and set the css. thats possible yes?

Comment: Just make the parent div display table, add a new div of display table-row inside and the children table-cell inside the table-row. When using tables, divs adjust to fit size of elements. This will automatically gives you the parent width a size, you don't need to count the size of the children to calc the parent width, it will be done automatically :)

Comment: that is really good to know. thanks for your info, nice to see all people aren't like Rob.